# Python: For loop only iterates once - also using a with statement

Tags: python, for-loop, with-statement, pdftotext

I am trying to open a zip file and iterate through the PDFs in the zip file. I want to scrape a certain portion of the text in the pdf. I am using the following code:

```
def get_text(part):
    #Create path
    path = f'C:\\Users\\user\\Data\\Part_{part}.zip'
    
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as data:
        listdata = data.namelist()
        onlypdfs = [k for k in listdata if '_2018' in k or '_2019' in k or '_2020' in k or '_2021' in k or '_2022' in k]

        for file in onlypdfs:
            with data.open(file, "r") as f:
                #Get the pdf
                pdffile = pdftotext.PDF(f)
                text = ("\n\n".join(pdffile))

    
                #Remove the newline characters
                text = text.replace('\r\n', ' ')
                text = text.replace('\r', ' ')
                text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
                text = text.replace('\x0c', ' ')

                #Get the text that will talk about what I want
                try:
                    text2 = re.findall(r'FEES (.+?) Types', text, re.IGNORECASE)[-1]

                except:
                    text2 = 'PROBLEM'

                #Return the file name and the text
                return file, text2
```

Then in the next line I am running:

```
info = []
for i in range(1,2):
    info.append(get_text(i))
info
```

My output is only the first file and text. I have 4 PDFs in the zip folder. Ideally, I want it to iterate through the 30+ zip files. But I am having trouble with just one.
I've seen this question asked before, but the solutions didn't fit my problem. Is it something with the with statement?

Comment: Is this line working?: ```onlypdfs = [k for k in listdata if '_2018' in k or '_2019' in k or '_2020' in k or '_2021' in k or '_2022' in k]```  Do you get a list of all the pdf's you're trying to open?

Comment: Yes, I see all 4 PDFs.

Comment: Your `return` call is indented inside your `with` statement but should be outside your `for` loop

Comment: When I move the return statement outside the for loop (in line with the first with statement), I only get the last file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process all the files and store each of them as you iterate. An example of how you could do this is to store them in a list of tuples:

```
file_list = []
for file in onlypdfs:
    ...
    file_list.append((file, text2)
return file_list
```

You could then use this like so:

```
info = []
for i in range(1,2):
    list = get_text(i)
    for file_text in list:
        info.append(file_text)
print(info)
```

Comment: This would create a different list for each zip file right? That wasn't my intent, but I think this is probably the cleanest idea.

Comment: Yep, but if you want to join them into a list you can do that too. I've updated the usage code to show how you would make a list of tuples of file + contents for all zips in a range

Comment: Thanks - This works. Instead of returning the list, I have saved it as a pickle file. I'll then combine all the pickle files in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the return statement on this line: `return file, text2`, you exit the for loop, skipping the other pdf's that you want to be reading.

The solution is to move the return statement outside of the for loop.

Comment: When I move the return statement outside the for loop (in line with the first with statement), I only get the last file.

Comment: Do you know return works?  You need to actually store the data from all four pdf's before you return from the function

Comment: No, this seems to be the problem.